# Google Play Developer support not responding to emails

Tags: google-play-console

I can't for the life of me get a response from Google Play support.  I have 2 apps that were removed because they have the same code base even though they are branded differently and this is on purpose and there is nothing we can do about it, it's how the two companies want it.  Anyway, I'm trying to make my appeal and it's been almost a month and not a word from anyone at Google.  I first responded to their emails where they notified me the apps were removed and provided links to make an appeal which I used but heard nothing back over a week.  So I went to the Google Play Console help and made an appeal there, waited over a week and heard nothing back.  Then I went to Google General help and told them the same story I'm telling you but still haven't heard anything.  I've been watching my email and spam filters like a hawk and I've made sure I'm using the email on the Google Play account but still nothing.  I also keep checking for messages or alerts within Google Play Console website.

What can I do to get help from Google?

Comment: Have you tried the chat support?

Comment: How long did it take for this issue to be resolved?

Comment: @rdsarna I didn't realize they were responding but my account had a different email box that I hadn't been checking, lol

Answer (score 4):

I guess as Pierre said (give him the points), use chat support.  Here is the response from chat if you are interested:

```
Phil 11:52 AM
You are now connected to Phil . Please type your message and hit 'Enter' to send.
Phil 11:52 AM
Hi there, thanks for contacting Google Play Developer Support!

There will be a short survey at the end of our chat so you can provide feedback on the service I'm providing.

Please give me a moment while I review your issue.
Me 11:52 AM
ok
Phil 11:53 AM
May I please have the package name of the app you're referring to? Package names generally look like "com.package.example"
Me 11:53 AM
<REDACTED> and <REDACTED>
Phil 11:54 AM
Thanks, Please give me a second as I check this! Be right back
Me 11:54 AM
...both were removed
Phil 11:55 AM
I apologize, policy support is beyond my scope of assistance
Phil 11:55 AM
I see that your case has been routed to the appropriate team and they will get back to you through email
Me 11:56 AM
Oh
Me 11:56 AM
Well they asked for 72 hours
Me 11:56 AM
it's been a couple weeks now
Me 11:56 AM
!!!!
Phil 11:56 AM
I apologize for the inconvenience
Phil 11:56 AM
The appropriate team will get back to you through email
Me 11:57 AM
Do you know what email address they'll respond to by any chance, that way I know which one to watch like a hawk?
Me 11:57 AM
it could be <REDACTED> or it could be <REDACTED>
Me 11:57 AM
I have no idea
Phil 11:58 AM
Please let me know which is a good email to reach you and I will add a note to reach you in that email
Me 11:58 AM
<REDACTED> is the best
Phil 11:58 AM
Great, I will add this email to the response
Phil 11:59 AM
Is there anything else I can help you with today?
Me 11:59 AM
Yes
Me 11:59 AM
Who can I contact to get some sort of time-table?
Me 11:59 AM
This is pretty important, lol
Phil 12:00 PM
I apologize, the appropriate team will have to get back to you through email
Me 12:00 PM
Any idea how long my company has to wait?
Phil 12:01 PM
Because my team and I are not involved in this, I cannot give you an estimated time . Let me know if you have questions using play console and I'm happy to help
Me 12:01 PM
Is there someone on that team I can contact to get a status?
Phil 12:02 PM
The appropriate team will get back to you through email and you can follow up with them
Me 12:02 PM
The bigger the company, the worse the support
Phil 12:02 PM
I apologize for the inconvenience
Me 12:03 PM
Thanks anyway, you are doing what you are told
Me 12:03 PM
Have a great day!
```

Comment: @MujtabaFR Yes.  I forgot to come back to this SO post later and apologize (partly) on Google's behalf.  I didn't realize the email address I was registered under, so Google had been contacting me but I didn't see the emails.  Anyway, there was nothing Google could do for me, the apps were removed and they could care less that these were real business apps branded differently for 2 different companies.  We consolidated the 2 branded apps into a single app and dynamically changed the branding based on login ...if I remember correctly.